# What is a standard order for learning/practicing scales when learning how to play the electric bass (esp. for jazz/blues music)?

Tags: scales, bass-guitar, jazz, blues

I'd like to bring my theoretical knowledge and practical skill for playing jazz/blues scales on the electric bass up to snuff. What is the standard order for learning/practicing jazz/blues scales on the bass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order might vary, but usually it is arranged so you get the ones that you will use the most first, but it doesn't really matter. You can google pages and pages that have fingerings for these.

One benefit we have with a stringed instrument is that there are patterns and shapes that each scale makes. The shape you learn for one major scale is the same for all major scales. We have it a lot easier than other instruments in that regard.

- Major Scale - C D E F G A B C - This scale also gives you dominant, and two versions of minor, just keep the same notes, but begin in a different place.

  > A. Dominant - G A B C D E F G (same notes, just start on G) 
  > B. Minor ( Dorian )- D E F G A B C D - start on D 
  > C. Minor (Natural) - A B C D E F G A - start on A
- Melodic Minor - C D Eb F G A B C - The next most common form of minor scale.
- Pentatonic - C D E G A C or the minor version A C D E G A

Check out this free PDF for theory and various scales:

http://www.jazzbooks.com/mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=FQBK&Store_Code=JAJAZZ